# Performance in embedded systems

Tags: ubuntu, qml

I'm develop a QML application for arm, but a got a problem when I compile the application in a cl-som-imx7 the performance is very slowly, this too happens when I compile a application with just a textbox this is whit QML, with C++ the performance is good, somebody know how can I do for give more resources to my application or something for a better performance

Comment: did you used pxp support for imx 7? and are you  using Qt5/X11??

Comment: @Sivanageswararao.Vadalasetti I'm using x11 but i'm not shure that I use pxp support, How could I see this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Add `Qt5` to your image and enable `pxp` support.

For Qt5 support add below lines in local.conf

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " qtconnectivity bluez5 qtbase qtbase-fonts qtbase-plugins imx-lib imx-test imx-gst1.0-plugin gstreamer1.0-plugins-imx gstreamer1.0-meta-base gstreamer1.0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav"
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-meta packagegroup-fsl-gstreamer1.0-commercial "
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qtmultimedia = " alsa gstreamer"
```

For `PXP` support follow below

```
vi meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtbase_%.bbappend .
```

add below lines

```
PACKAGECONFIG_GL_imxpxp   = "gles2"
QT_CONFIG_FLAGS_APPEND_imxpxp = "${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'x11', '-no-eglfs', '-eglfs', d)}"
```

Comment: Hi! I got a problem because this instruction dosn't work 

`vi meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtbase_%.bbappend .`

and if I remoce this line the other lines works

Answer (score -1):

You need full openGL acceleration and a a custom build of Qt to run a Qt App.

Are you using yocto?

Comment: Yes! I'm using Yocto

Comment: try eglfs backend:  your_binary -platform eglfs